# Is it possible to manage available memory for RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm playing with a big dataset(raw .csv takes 225mb on the disk.):

`>dim(train)
[1] 535713     52`

When I try to make a logistic regression with `glm` I see rsession starts consuming 60gb of memory

[image]

After memory is out - I get r session aborted, r encountered fatal error, the session was terminated. Is it possible to prevent such behavior?

My tools:

- RStudio Version 1.1.383
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- R version 3.4.1

Here is a session info output: https://gist.github.com/iamtodor/4b73af7bc490e38c8f8ad61785200bf2

Diagnostic report output: https://gist.github.com/iamtodor/3dd2c395c311942bc922ea38b16e80d0
Code: https://gist.github.com/iamtodor/c39042e9577007b8feffa8128a065170
It crashes on 8th line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated the reason.
It was a column id in the dataset, that provides some hashcode, for example, `nb5059fbc40534a1`.

Just want to add the solution, it could be worth for someone

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `biglm` package for R: [link1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/biglm.pdf) or `speedglm`: [link2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/speedglm/speedglm.pdf)